# Saving a PDF to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have code to write a file to save a PDF and then upload it to s3. What I have works perfectly in dev. but not in production.

```
def upload_to_s3(pdf)
  save_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdfs/invoice_#{@invoice.id}.pdf"
  f = File.new(save_path, 'w:ASCII-8BIT')
  f.write(pdf)
  uploader = InvoiceUploader.new
  File.open(save_path) { |file| uploader.store!(file) }
  @invoice.update(pdf: uploader.url)
  File.delete(save_path)
  uploader.url
end
```

Stack Trace:

```
Rendered invoices/pdf.html.erb (6.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1420ms (ActiveRecord: 34.6ms)
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/deploy/reputation/releases/20180401031049/tmp/pdfs/invoice_2.pdf):
app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:140:in `initialize'
[5e443877-e7fe-4848-847b-f5f6159e7db9] 
app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:140:in `new'
[5e443877-e7fe-4848-847b-f5f6159e7db9] 
app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:140:in `upload_to_s3'
[5e443877-e7fe-4848-847b-f5f6159e7db9] 
app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:65:in `pdf'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly states:

> Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - `/home/deploy/reputation/releases/20180401031049/tmp/pdfs/invoice_2.pdf`): ...

Create the directory `/home/deploy/reputation/releases/20180401031049/tmp/pdfs/` in production upfront. Since it’s dynamic (dependent on the release datetime,) it’s better to create it in your ruby code:

```
save_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdfs/"
Dir.mkdir(save_dir)

save_path = ...
```

Comment: ha thanks. Clearly I've been staring at this for too long